# Sum of all loop values | Vuejs | Javascript | Element table

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, element

Looping the list of values in element.io table. I need to display the sum of list of weights. I am unable to sum all the weight values.

```
var val= [ 
  { 
    "NmVehiclePlanning.deliveryBranch": "Madurai", 
    "NmVehiclePlanning.deliveryCity": "Madurai", 
    "NmVehiclePlanning.weight": 30106 
  }, 
  { 
    "NmVehiclePlanning.deliveryBranch": "Madurai", 
    "NmVehiclePlanning.deliveryCity": "Virudhunagar", 
    "NmVehiclePlanning.weight": 3498 
  }, 
  { 
    "NmVehiclePlanning.deliveryBranch": "Madurai", 
    "NmVehiclePlanning.deliveryCity": "KANYAKUMARI", 
    "NmVehiclePlanning.weight": 500 
  },  ]
```

The above data is my json data. Need to sum of all (Key name: NmVehiclePlanning.weight)

```
<el-table-column label="weight">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        <span v-for="data in scope.row.details">
            {{ data['NmVehiclePlanning.weight'] }}
        </span>
     </template>
</el-table-column>
```

Received value is

```
30106 3498 500
```

Expected value is

```
34104
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this. Hope it will work

```
<el-table-column label="weight">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        {{ calculateSum(scope.row.details) }}
    </template>
</el-table-column>
```

Add this function in your script.

```
calculateSum(val){
    var sum = 0;
    for(let value in val){
        sum += val[value]['NmVehiclePlanning.weight']
    }
    return sum;
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to calculate this value in your javaScript and then display the sum.

```
calculateSum(){
    var sum = 0;
    for(let value in val){
        sum += value['NmVehiclePlanning.weight']
    }
    return sum;
}
```